# Using feed_dict is more than 5x faster than using dataset API?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I created a dataset in TFRecord format for testing. Every entry contains 200 columns, named `C1` - `C199`, each being a strings list, and a `label` column to denote the labels. The code to create the data can be found here: https://github.com/codescv/tf-dist/blob/8bb3c44f55939fc66b3727a730c57887113e899c/src/gen_data.py#L25

Then I used a linear model to train the data. The first approach looks like this:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(data_file)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=batch_size*10)
dataset = dataset.map(parse_tfrecord, num_parallel_calls=5)
dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

features, labels = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()    
logits = tf.feature_column.linear_model(features=features, feature_columns=columns, cols_to_vars=cols_to_vars)
train_op = ...

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(train_op)
```

The full code can be found here: https://github.com/codescv/tf-dist/blob/master/src/lr_single.py

When I run the code above, I get 0.85 steps/sec (batch size being 1024).

In the second approach, I manually get batches from Dataset into python, then feed them to a placeholder, like this:

```
example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None])
features = tf.parse_example(example, features=tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(columns+[tf.feature_column.numeric_column('label', dtype=tf.float32, default_value=0)]))
labels = features.pop('label')
train_op = ...

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(data_file).repeat().batch(batch_size)
next_batch = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    data_batch = sess.run(next_batch)
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={example: data_batch})
```

The full code can be found here: https://github.com/codescv/tf-dist/blob/master/src/lr_single_feed.py

When I run the code above, I get 5 steps/sec. That is 5x faster than the first approach. This is what I do not understand, because theoretically the second should be slower due to the extra serialization/deserialization of data batches.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is currently (as of TensorFlow 1.9) a performance issue when using `tf.data` to map and batch tensors that have a large number of features with a small amount of data in each. The issue has two causes:

1. The `dataset.map(parse_tfrecord, ...)` transformation will execute O(`batch_size` * `num_columns`) small operations to create a batch. By contrast, feeding a `tf.placeholder()` to `tf.parse_example()` will execute O(1) operations to create the same batch.
2. Batching many `tf.SparseTensor` objects using `dataset.batch()` is much slower than directly creating the same `tf.SparseTensor` as the output of `tf.parse_example()`.

Improvements to both these issues are underway, and should be available in a future version of TensorFlow. In the meantime, you can improve the performance of the `tf.data`-based pipeline by switching the order of the `dataset.map()` and `dataset.batch()` and rewriting the `dataset.map()` to work on a vector of strings, like the feeding based version:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(data_file)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=batch_size*10)
dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)

# Batch first to create a vector of strings as input to the map(). 
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

def parse_tfrecord_batch(record_batch):
  features = tf.parse_example(
      record_batch,
      features=tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(
          columns + [
              tf.feature_column.numeric_column(
                  'label', dtype=tf.float32, default_value=0)]))
  labels = features.pop('label')
  return features, labels

# NOTE: Parallelism might not be as useful, because the individual map function now does
# more work per invocation, but you might want to experiment with this.
dataset = dataset.map(parse_tfrecord_batch)

# Add a prefetch at the end to pipeline execution.
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)

features, labels = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()    
# ...
```

---

**EDIT (2018/6/18)**: To answer your questions from the comments:

> 1. Why is `dataset.map(parse_tfrecord, ...)` O(`batch_size` * `num_columns`), not O(`batch_size`)? If parsing requires enumeration of the columns, why doesn't parse_example take O(`num_columns`)?

When you wrap TensorFlow code in a `Dataset.map()` (or other functional transformation) a constant number of extra operations per output are added to "return" values from the function and (in the case of `tf.SparseTensor` values) "convert" them to a standard format. When you directly pass the outputs of `tf.parse_example()` to the input of your model, these operations aren't added.  While they are very small operations, executing so many of them can become a bottleneck.  (Technically the parsing *does* take O(`batch_size` * `num_columns`) **time**, but the constants involved in parsing are much smaller than executing an operation.)

> 2. Why do you add a prefetch at the end of the pipeline?

When you're interested in performance, this is almost always the best thing to do, and it should improve the overall performance of your pipeline. For more information about best practices, see the [performance guide for `tf.data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have just confirmed that switching map and batch really works. Still I am not quite sure about two things: 1. Why is dataset.map(parse_tfrecord, ...)  O(batch_size * num_columns), not O(batch_size) ? If parsing requires enumeration of the columns, why doesn't parse_example take o(num_columns) ?  2.  Why do you add a prefetch at the end of the pipeline?

Comment: Great questions! The answers are a bit too long for a comment, so I added them to the main answer above.

Comment: @mrry Is this still an issue for TF 1.14?