# Tensorflow Data pipeline

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am new to both Tensorflow and StackOverflow. I have a question related to [Using feed_dict is more than 5x faster than using dataset API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781373/using-feed-dict-is-more-than-5x-faster-than-using-dataset-api).

I see that the recommended solution using the tf.data-based pipeline involves using repeat() before batch(). If one is not going to shuffle between epochs - as seems to be the case here - wouldn't it much faster to cache() after map() and follow that with repeat().

Comment: Can you test it for yourself? Are you having troubles with benchmarking the two approaches?

Comment: I did test it. It is indeed much faster (and does not hit an out-of-memory limit if number of epochs is very large) if it is done the way I suggest (at least for my problem which involves reading in 14000 tfRecord files, each containing 2160 records of 18 columns of floating point numers). I was wondering if I was simply missing something since mrry is the expert.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. The linked question and answer do not include any mention of cache (and advice might change after years). Is your question whether you should use cache for your use case?

TensorFlow has some general advice on performance (including caching): https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance

Comment: I was wondering why cache was not used in the linked case before using repeat because there does not seem to be any shufflng in the linked case.

Comment: By the way, I was hoping to get @mrry to see this question - not sure how to do that in StackOverflow