# TensorFlow use dataset to replace function feed_dict

Tags: python, tensorflow

when I learn a tensorflow project,find one line code:

```
cls_prob, box_pred = sess.run([output_cls_prob, output_box_pred], feed_dict={input_img: blob})
```

But, this line code It took a lot of time. (use CPU need 15 seconds...┭┮﹏┭┮)

By consulting information, I find use function 'dataset' could solve this problem which took a lot of time, How should I use it?

source of 'blob':

```
img = cv2.imread('./imgs/001.jpg')
img_scale = float(600) / min(img_data.shape[0], img_data.shape[1])
if np.round(img_scale * max(img_data.shape[0], img_data.shape[1])) > 1200:
    img_scale = float(1200) / max(img_data.shape[0], img_data.shape[1])
img_data = cv2.resize(img_data, None, None, fx=img_scale, fy=img_scale, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
img_orig = img_data.astype(np.float32, copy=True)
blob = np.zeros((1, img_data.shape[0], img_data.shape[1], 3),dtype=np.float32)
blob[0, 0:img_data.shape[0], 0:img_data.shape[1], :] = img_orig
```

source of 'output_cls_prob'&'output_box_pred'&'input_img':

```
# Actually,read PB model...
input_img = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('Placeholder:0')
output_cls_prob = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('Reshape_2:0')
output_box_pred = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('rpn_bbox_pred/Reshape_1:0')
```

Parameter type：

```
blob：type 'numpy.ndarray'

output_cls_prob：class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'

output_box_pred：class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'

input_img：class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'
```

Comment: `tf.data` is the recommended API for tensorflow input pipelines. Here is a tutorial on tensorflow.org: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets. If you provide more information on how you get the value `blob` to be fed, people on stackoverflow may be able to give a more concrete code snippet on how `tf.data` can be used in this case.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that the code has been supplementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.data` is the recommended API for tensorflow input pipelines. Here is a tutorial on [tensorflow.org](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets). For your example, the section ["Decoding image data and resizing it"](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#decoding_image_data_and_resizing_it) could be most useful. For example, you could do something like:

```
# Reads an image from a file, decodes it into a dense tensor, and resizes it
# to a fixed shape.
def _parse_function(filename):
  image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
  image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string)
  image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [new_width, new_height])
  image_resized = tf.expand_dims(image_resized, 0)  # Adds size 1 dimension
  return image_resized

# A vector of filenames.
filenames = tf.constant(["./imgs/001.jpg", ...])

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
```

And instead of having `input_img` be a placeholder, change:

```
input_img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
output_class_prob, output_class_pred = (... use input_img ...)
```

to:

```
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
input_img = iterator.get_next()
output_class_prob, output_class_pred = (... use input_img ...)
```

Comment: uh...I only have one picture.But the picture is too large.so,The computation time of the model is too long.uh..um...Am I wrong?

Comment: If you don't use the image at full resolution, it might make sense to preprocess the file so that it's smaller?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know that the use of Dataset API has a great impact in performance when multiples GPUs are used... Otherwise is almost identical to feed_dict. I recommend you to read [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50889965/8380638) from a TF developer, it has almost everything one needs to know to create a mental image of the benefits of this new API.

Comment: The benefits of the data API are more pronounced in distributed settings, but it can have a significant impact on single-GPU environments too, since it reduces the exchange of memory between Python and the TensorFlow runtime and GPU, it can prefetch data while GPU processing is taking place and it can parallelize data reading. And it can be very helpful with big datasets that do not fit in memory too.

Comment: thanks,but 'blob' is very large really,I think it takes up a lot of memory.